# Azure Appservice + COSMOSDB_ ENOBUFS ERROR

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-appservice

I am using node version 10.6.0 and connects to Azure COSMOS DB using 'MongoCllient'. Code as below:

**index.js**

```
var MongodbConnectionString = process.env.COSMOS;

server.post('/api/test/',(req,res,next) =>{

 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect(MongodbConnectionString, {
     useNewUrlParser: true
    }, function (err, client) {

var db = client.db("DBname");
//rest of the code
}
});
```

Node application is hosted on ***azure app service*** and works fine. But after many http request i am getting error

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [URI:PORT] on first
> connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ENOBUFS - Local
> (undefined:undefined)]

If I restart the ***azure app service***, application is up and running , maybe like after 2 days same issue popups and need to restart app service again.

How it could be resolved? Please help me out

Comment: Hello @am831 - Have you tried setting the database URL inside the code to use this parameter 'authSource',  
 Something like this - mongodb://myUserName:example/databaseName?authSource=admin

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the above as answer, since that should resolve your problem.

Try setting the database URL inside the code to use this parameter 'authSource', Something like this - mongodb://myUserName:example/databaseName?authSource=admin –